# If every function in haskell is curried then how come i can't create partial pairs?

Tags: haskell, currying

Noob here. Im not sure if every function is supposed to be curried (but thats the feeling I got).

If that is indeed the case then how come

```
(,) 1
```

throws an error? Shouldn't it return a function that when applied to one more value gives a tuple?

Comment: In ghci, you can use `:t` (`:type`) to check the inferred type of expressions in general, and functions in particular https://downloads.haskell.org/ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/ghci.html#ghci-cmd-:type

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> how come `(,) 1` throws an error? Shouldn't it return a function *[...]*?

Both of those can be true.

```
λ> let f = (,) 1 in f 2
(1,2)
```

But since functions have no `Show` instance, just typing `(,) 1` *does* throw an error:

```
λ> (,) 1

<interactive>:4:1: error:
    • No instance for (Show (b0 -> (Integer, b0)))
        arising from a use of ‘print’
        (maybe you haven't applied a function to enough arguments?)
    • In a stmt of an interactive GHCi command: print it
```

Comment: Just to make it dead simple for other noobs like me to understand. The error in the repl when typing what I typed in my question is not because applying the tuple function to a single argument is not allowed, but because the repl immediately tries to show the result after performing that operation. And the result is a function that doesn't implement Show and hence cannot be shown.

Comment: @gautam1168 Yes, that is correct. (And in fact you will get the same error if you try to show any other function in the REPL.)